# Partition date ranges in partitioned tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible to select the partition date range based on some other date in the same GBQ table?

_partitiondate is of datatype timestamp

purchase_date is of datatype string

Below is what I am trying to do-

```
_PARTITIONDATE < DATE(CAST(purchase_date as TIMESTAMP))
and _PARTITIONDATE >= date_add(date(CAST(purchase_date as TIMESTAMP)), interval -30 day)
```

I get the following error-

```
Cannot query over table 'project.dataset.table' without a filter over column(s) '_PARTITION_LOAD_TIME', '_PARTITIONDATE', '_PARTITIONTIME' that can be used for partition elimination
```

Comment: Could you provide the full query which you are trying? I think one of the tables in your query is created using 'require partition filter' and you need to apply partition condition for that table as well. And yes, we can select the partition date range based on some other date fields using cast methods in bigquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is documented that it is possible (see [Querying partitions using pseudo colums](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_using_pseudo_columns) for more details), below it is the structure recommmended in documentation:

```
_PARTITIONDATE >= "2018-01-29" AND _PARTITIONDATE < "2018-01-30"
```

or

```
_PARTITIONDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-02'
```

The thing is that, as you correctly suggested, the comparision value should be a TIMESTAMP data type, so a different approach can be:

```
_PARTITIONDATE < TIMESTAMP(purchase_date)
and _PARTITIONDATE >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(purchase_date), interval -30 day)
```

I think something like the following should work:

```
SELECT
  columns
FROM
  dataset.table
WHERE
  _PARTITIONDATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(purchase_date), interval 30 day)
  AND TIMESTAMP(purchase_date)
```